# PHP: различия между двумя вариантами альтернативного синтаксиса управляющих структур

Tags: php

Для примера возьмём управляющую конструкцию `if`.

---

Есть такой вариант использования:

```
<?php if ( $a ) : ?>

    Блаблабла

<?php endif; ?>
```

---

А есть и такой:

```
<?php if ( $a ) { ?>

    Блаблабла

<?php } ?>
```

---

Фиддл: [sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2303090b044e30453c9ff7e39d639ad5d26e1ad).

---

**Есть ли какие-либо различия между ними?**

Comment: Нет, абсолютно никаких. Но первый вариант используют для шаблонизации и только в ней. И тег `<?php` не обязательно писать, можно просто `<?`, тогда получится шаблонный код ещё короче:   `<? if ($a) : ?> .... <? endif; ?>`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Можно ли писать сокращенно <? указано в php.ini (параметр short_open_tag) и в последних версиях php по умолчанию сокращенная запись выключена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Различие только в синтаксисе, поведение и логика использоваться полностью эквивалентна. Читается, что форма

```
if ( $a ) :
```

более удобна при смещении PHP и HTML-кодов: проще ориентироваться где закрывается тот или иной блок. Однако, такое смещение не особо приветствуется сообществом, поэтому такая форма практически не используется. В подавляющем большинстве случаев предпочтение отдается форме

```
if ( $a ) {
```

Comment: А мне тут некоторое время назад на SO сообщество говорило, что первая форма в последнее время больше приветствуется и рекомендовало в примерах кода на SO придерживаться ее :)

Comment: @Mike, в шаблонах? Возможно. Если честно сам предпочитаю шаблоны без угловых скобок, типа <% или <?php. Возможно в шаблонах такого типа первый вариант смотрелся бы более уместно.

Comment: Рекомендовали везде. хотя вторая форма мне явно больше нравится т.к. идет со времен C и во многих языках присутствует и интуитивно понятна

Comment: Если честно удивлен, так как тоже всегда отдаю предпочтение C-форме. Да и PSR стандарты первую форму помоему вообще не упоминают, а это серьезный показатель.

Comment: Я изучаю Yii2 и везде встречал (**в шаблонах**) использование первого варианта (например, [вот](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html#creating-view) в документации есть немного) и сам его использую. А сейчас смотрел видео и там автор использует второй вариант — поэтому заинтересовал этот момент. Но первый вариант действительно позволяет *... проще ориентироваться где закрывается тот или иной блок. ...*.

Answer (score 1):

Тернарный оператор:

Плюсы:

- Меньше кода

Минусы:

- дольше выполняется (заметно при большой нагрузке и больших значениях итераций циклов)
- немного уложняется понимание (при больших уровнях вложенности)
- нельзя оставить if без else т.е

если было

```
if ($a === $b) {  echo "111"; } else { echo "222"; }
echo ($a === $b) ? "333" : "444";
```

а потом потребуется убрать else

```
if ($a === $b) {  echo "111"; } 
echo ($a === $b) ? "333";  //ошибка  так сделать нельзя нужно переписывать на if
```